# CSS Estilo es línea: el navegador me cambia valores del background a su defecto

Tags: javascript, html, css

Por qué cuando asigno estilo en línea, un fondo a un elemento div.

cuando yo le pongo: `url("imgs/playerSheet.png")`

el navegador me agrega esto: `transparent url("imgs/playerSheet.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%`

a traves de la consola lo vacío, y compruebo y es correcto está vacío. pero cuando le vuelvo a asignar la url. nuevamente se agrega todo eso.

uso firefox, 52.0.2 (32-bit). Si hace falta subo el código. pero es mucho, por eso preferí ir al grano directamente. Gracias.

Comment: Hola , puedes poner el código de ejemplo por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes usar:

```
background-image: url("imgs/playerSheet.png");
```

Comment: Por favor mira [answer]. Por que crees que esto va a solucionar el problema de OP? las respuestas deben ser lo mas completa posibles.

Comment: Gracias se solucionó. De todas formas es raro, esto lo que me pasa. Intentaré subir el constructor más adelante.